# Работа с mysql php Добавление, обновление записей.

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Задача такова: Нам нужно сделать авторизацию через Фейсбук. После этой авторизации должно выводиться "Добро пожаловать UserName! Дата последнего посещения: LastVisit". Через app на фейсбуке мы можно сказать получаем массив из данных и присваиваем его переменной-массиву ($userInfo). После нажатия кнопки авторизации получаем данные с Фейсбука и заносим их в БД. Но перед тем как занести, мы должны проверить нет ли юзера с таким id в нашей БД. Если он есть, то выводится привествие с датой последнего захода, иначе, мы выводим только приветствие. $userInfo[] <- массив с данными с Фейсбука. При выполнении этого кода(именно с sql запросами) выдаёт ошибку: "Удаленный сервер или файл не найден". Я начинающий, так что очень хочется разобраться. Таблица в БД называется users, в ней есть поля, все varchar: name, socid, data.

```
$namesql = $userInfo['name'];
$idsql = $userInfo['id'];
$tek_data = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");

if ($result) {
echo "Здравствуйте, ",$namesql,"! Вы авторизировались через Фейсбук!<br>";
    $sql = mysqli_connect('localhost','*','*','*') or die("Ошибка подключения к БД!".mysqli_error($sql));
    $query = "SELECT socid FROM users";
    $resultsql = mysqli_query($sql, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultsql, MYSQLI_NUM);

        if(in_array("$idsql",$row)){
            $lastVisit = "SELECT date FROM users WHERE ($idsql = data)";
            $rezLastVisit = mysqli_query($sql, $lastVisit);
            echo "Последний визит: $rezLastVisit";
            $up_data = "UPDATE users SET (data = $tek_data) WHERE $idsql";
            $up_data_add = mysqli_query($sql, $up_data);
        }
        else{
            $new_user = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$namesql','$idsql','$tek_data')";
            $new_user_add = mysqli_query($sql, $new_user);
        }

    mysqli_close($sql);
}

}
```

Comment: Не понял вот этой строчки:

""Последний визит: $rezLastVisit";".

Предполагаю, что перед этим должно быть echo?
И лучше наверное вот так:
echo "Последний визит: " . $rezLastVisit;

Comment: Все верно, пропустил echo. Теперь весь код вроде как выполняется. Но в таблицу не заносится ничего => нет вывода последнего посещения. $row возвращает массив. Пробовал добавлять записи через phpmyadmin.
Нашёл ошибку, исправил. Теперь добавляется запись в таблицу. Но не выводит дату последнего посещения и не обновляется дата в таблице.

Comment: Разве в запросе на добавление ($new_user = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$namesql','$idsql','$tek_data')";) не нужно перечислить поля для заполнения (name, socid, data)?

Comment: Видимо нет. Все добавилось в таблицу. Я сейчас в университете прохожу предмет "банки и базы данных" и там сейчас работаем в FoxPro, программа не айс, но запросы sql строим и добавление в таблицу происходят либо INSERT INTO users (name, socid, data) VALUES ('','','') или как у меня.

Comment: Хм, интересно. А он сам догадается куда ему эти значения добавлять, если в данной таблице, к примеру, десяток полей?

Comment: Ну просто ты в VALUES () поочерёдно вводишь нужные тебе значения. Суть теперь не в добавлении. Меня интересуют запросы на вывод последнего посещения и обновлление даты. Что в них не так?